# firebase anonymous auth tied to device

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app for public information. So Signup isn't necessary. But, I want to provide a bit of personalization. In order to do this, I need to store the user activities on the server.

Is there a way to allow users to sign in anonymously but it is tied to the device, so in the case of the user delete or sign out then sign in again, they still have the same uid assigned from firebase auth?

It would be very nice to have a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently a feature if Firebase Authentication. If you want this, you'll have to build a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) for it yourself, probably translating some form of device ID to a user ID.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. will give it a go!